# Trying to prove statement with summation

Tags: proof-verification, summation

Let's say you have this set of numbers:

$$a_1, b_1, v_1, a_2, b_2, v_2, \cdots \text{ with } a_i \leq bi, a_i \geq 0, b_i \geq 0, v_i \geq 0.$$
Is the following always true?
$$\frac{\sum a_iv_i}{\sum v_i}\leq \frac{\sum b_iv_i}{\sum v_i}$$

Comment: Yes, via direct comparison.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use Mathjax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it is true.

To understand, do it step by step:

$$a_i\leqslant b_i$$

for all $i$, so

$$a_iv_i\leqslant b_iv_i.$$

for all $i$ since $v_i\geqslant for all $i$.

So

$$\sum a_iv_i\leqslant \sum b_iv_i.$$

Then you can divide by $\sum v_i$ since $\sum v_i> 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each term in the sum on the left is smaller than or equal to the corresponding term on the right, so the sum is too.